# time selecting with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used a time_select helper in order to select hour and minutes:

```
f.time_select( :time )
```

I want that the hours will be from the current time (Time.now).

For example if the time now is 21:00, the hours I would be able to select from will be:

21, 22 and 23 (and not 1,2,3...19,20 )

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the :default option?

You can find other possibilities to change the behavior of that helper method here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Comment: I dont understand how the default option can do this?